# focusin and focusout not working in iPhone 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone

I have a following Jquery code, it is working fine in web browser and in samsung device. but it is not working in iPhone 4. Thanks in advance.

```
 <script>
     $(document).on('focusin','#sendMessageText',function() { alert("in Focus");
        $("#body").css( "height", "90%" );
        $("#footer").addClass("hidden");
        $(".footerIcons").addClass("hidden");
    });
   $(document).on('focusout','#sendMessageText',function() { alert("focus out");
        $("#body").css( "height", "70%" );
        $("#footer").removeClass("hidden");
        $(".footerIcons").removeClass("hidden");
    });
 </script>
```